# Liferea http client

Tags: rss-aggregator

I have a website which filters http request by http client. Consequently, Liferea can't get the feed, but only a an error webpage.
So my questions are:

- what is the http-client header of liferea
- is it possible to get the source dowladed by liferea to see the webpage dowloaded, which contain an error code.

Comment: What makes you think that your assumption is actually true? Which website is it?

Comment: The responsable of the servor told me that. However, in my case, the problem was not here, but as I was not able to get the source dowloaded by liferea I was not able to see it. However, using wireshark I could read  it.